# Como ejecutar consulta linq en C#

Tags: sql-server, linq

Buen día, actualmente tengo una aplicación en C# Asp.net la cual usa identity membership, y tengo que llamar el nombre del rol con el que inicio sesion el usuario pensaba hacerlo con un query linq pero no se como hacerlo, alquien me podria guiar, actualmente esta es mi consulta en Sql Server:

```
SELECT a.Name from AspNetRoles a inner join AspNetUserRoles b on a.Id = b.RoleId where 
b.UserId = IdUser and b.StatusRol = 1
```

Comment: Estas utilizando **Entities** ?

Comment: No estoy usando entities

Comment: Entonces como accedes a tu base de datos ? deberias de subir el codigo que has intentado en C# Asp.net y decir que estas utilizando para realizar las consultas

Answer (score 0):

Se declara la conexion,
estableces la conexion
declaras la consulta y la ejecutas
lees el resultado

Aqui un ejemplo:

```
List<string> rolesPersona= new List<string>();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=TuBaseDeDatos;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT a.Name from AspNetRoles a inner join AspNetUserRoles b on a.Id = b.RoleId where 
b.UserId = IdUser and b.StatusRol = 1", connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // respuesta contine renglones 
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            // siguiente renglon
            while (reader.Read())
            {


                var persona= reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name"));

                rolesPersona.Add(p);
            }
        }
    }
}
//
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno tienes varias formas de hacer lo puedes usar **`Linq`** o `lambda`, pero ahora te dejo un ejemplo con **Linq**.

Suponiendo que ya tengas un objeto de la base de datos creada haces esto:

```
tipo variable = (from roles in objTuBaseDeDatos.AspNetRoles 
                 join userRoles in objTuBaseDeDatos.AspNetUserRoles on roles.Id equals userRoles.RoleId
                 where userRoles.UserId == IdUser && userRoles.StatusRol == 1
                 select roles.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

La variable "Variable" no es necesario puedes poner a retornar directamente.

Ahora suponiendo que no tengas un objeto de la base de datos  lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
try
{
  using (dbBaseDatosEntities objTuBaseDeDatos = new dbBaseDatosEntities())
  {
    tipo variable = (from roles in objTuBaseDeDatos.AspNetRoles 
                     join userRoles in objTuBaseDeDatos.AspNetUserRoles on roles.Id equals userRoles.RoleId
                     where userRoles.UserId == IdUser && userRoles.StatusRol == 1
                     select roles.Name).FirstOrDefault();
  }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(e.Message, e);
}
```

Todo esto como el ejemplo uno o el ejemplo dos van dentro de tu metodo.

Espero sea de ayuda.

Answer (score -1):

no he practicado linq en mucho tiempo pero creo que esto te puede servir

```
var data = from anr in AspNetRoles
join anur in AspNetUserRoles on anr.Id equals anur.RoleId
where anur.Userid == IdUser
where anur.StatusRol == 1
select new { name: anr.Name }
```

[Mas info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)